# Colunas não batem na inserção

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

Está dando um erro

> Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

[image: Meu código]

Comment: Pode postar o texto do código? Imagens fica ruim pra gente responder. É só copiar e colar aqui.

Comment: Você insere dados em apenas tres colunas e manda o banco de dados inserir dados em quatro colunas, assim não dá né! Tem que ter **insert into (coluna1, coluna2) values (valor1, valor2)**

Comment: Show @RenatoSilva

Answer (score 1):

Você tem 3 colunas e está tentando inserir 4 delas, por isso o erro.

Na verdade essa coluna `codliv` é esquisita. Se é um código do livro não deveria ser repetido, certo?

Eu acho que o que deseja é este código ser a chave primária, descrições textuais são ruins para chaves primárias já que é difícil digitar igual e pode até ter repetição. O código do livro deveria ser auto incrementado para garantir a unicidade. E nem precisa usá-lo quando for inserir, assim ele é colocado automaticamente pelo banco de dados.

Ficaria assim:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `livros` (
    `codigo` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `nome` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `autor` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `livros` (`nome`, `autor`) VALUES
    ('O grande Conflito', 'Ellen White'),
    ('O capital', 'Karl Marx'),
    ('O Manifesto Comunista', 'Karl Marx'),
    ('A Ideologia Alema', 'Karl Marx');
```

Veja [funcionando no **SQL Fiddle**](http://Veja%20funcionando%20no%20**ideone**.%20E%20no%20**Coding%20Ground**.%20Tamb%C3%A9m%20coloquei%20no%20**GitHub**%20para%20refer%C3%AAncia%20futura.). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/Columns.sql).

Answer (score 1):

Você está querendo inserir 4 valores na tabela, porém a tabela só tem 3 colunas.

Outra coisa na coluna `nome` varchar(10) não vai comportar nomes com mais de 10 letras, portanto aumente esse comprimento.

Como a primeira coluna é numérica e sequencial, basta criar uma coluna `id` que incrementa automaticamente um valor a cada novo insert na tabela

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `livros` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `nome` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  `autor` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  `codliv` INT(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`codliv`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `livros` (`nome`, `autor`, `codliv`) VALUES
('O grande Conflito', 'Ellen White', 1),
('O capital', 'Karl Marx', 1),
('O Manifesto Comunista', 'Karl Marx', 3),
('A Ideologia Alema', 'Karl Marx', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

### O problema

> "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

Em português:

> "A contagem de colunas não corresponde à contagem de valores na linha 1"

#### Solução

`INSERT INTO livros (codliv, nome, autor) VALUES
(1, 'O grande Conflito', 'Ellen White'),
(2, 'O capital', 'Karl Marx'),
(3, 'O Manifesto Comunista', 'Karl Marx'),
(4, 'A Ideologia Alema', 'Karl Marx');`

#### Minha sugestão

[Veja clicando aqui!](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf7c54/1)